# Why do functions work in class file when #include <cstring> is in source file?

Tags: visual-c++

I'm using **VS 2013**, and **Horton C++ 2010**.

My chapter exercise, `Ex9_01.cpp`, has `strcpy_s()` and `strlen()` in the class file `CandyBox.h` and it didn't work until I `"#include cstring"` in in `CandyBox.h`.

Then as I read more of the example I saw that `"#include cstring"` was in the source file, `Ex9_01.cpp`, so I removed `"cstring"` from `CandyBox.h` and example stilled worked!
WHY? 
 
Since the file `Candybox.h` doesn't `"#include Ex9_01.cpp"` why does it look at `Ex9_01.cpp` to know about `'cstring'`?

P.S.
Sorry about poor formatting, this is my first post at site and I guess I didn't read all the instructions.  Will do better next time (am short of time now, running for an airplane).

Astro

Comment: Please provide code examples, your question is too fragmented and rushed

Comment: @Astro Boy Please try to make your "Question" net & explain details about your exact point of need. If it's about "code", then provide it in details. If you face with some error then show them too. And overall try to follow the stackoverflow "Ask question" rules and regulations. By following this the possibility of getting your question's answer is high. Enjoy. -Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Tulon. I'll be better in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler only looks at cpp files. An h file only gets compiled when it is #include'ed in a cpp file, just as if it had been pasted there. So what probably happens in your case is that the cpp file includes cstring.h, then it includes candybox.h. So cstring.h is "seen" before candybox.h.

Comment: OMG, that's it!!! This answers a lot of the problems that I have had. I wish the book had stated the compiler only looked at cpp files. That's the trouble with trying to learn on one's own.